# Bootstrap ColorPicker not working on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is the following. I have a button that adds text inputs. One of them will save a color code. For a better user experience I want that color to be chosen with the Boostrap ColorPicker plugin. My problem is that when I generate the boxes The text box does not detect the plugin, however for a text box that is not dynamic if it detects it. Below I put a link of an example with all the code with the fixed text box and the button that dynamically generates them. Thanks in advance.

[Link example](https://codepen.io/jes-s-soto-mitjans/pen/eYdYgbj)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
  <title>Colorpicker using Bootstrap 3</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.3/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.3/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-6">
    <label for="">Example picker</label>
    <div id="" class="cp-component input-group">      
        <input type="text" value="#269faf" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-azul"                         id="insertar_intervalo">
   <div class="intervalos">
     
   </div>
  </div>
 


</body>
 
</html>
```

JS file

```
  $('.cp-component').colorpicker();
    var contador = 0;
    $(document.body).on('click', '#insertar_intervalo', function (e) {
        contador = contador + 1;
        $('.intervalos').append(
            `
                            <div class="well well-sm contenedor-intervalos"id="contenedor-intervalo-${contador}">
                                <div class="row fila-contenido-evaluaciones">
                                    <div class=" col-md-4">
                                        <label for="">Desde</label>
                                        <input type="text"name="desdes[]"class="desdes form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-4">
                                        <label for="">Hasta</label>
                                        <input type="text"name="hastas[]"class="hastas form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-4">
                                        <label for="">Color</label>
                                      <div id="cp-component-${contador}" class="cp-component input-group">
                                          <input type="text" value="#269faf" class="form-control" />
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
        `
        );

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the html content you need to run the colorpicker again:

```
$('.cp-component').colorpicker();

var contador = 0;

$(document.body).on('click', '#insertar_intervalo', function (e) {
    contador = contador + 1;
    $('.intervalos').append(
        `
        <div class="well well-sm contenedor-intervalos"id="contenedor-intervalo-${contador}">
            <div class="row fila-contenido-evaluaciones">
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                    <label for="">Desde</label>
                    <input type="text"name="desdes[]"class="desdes form-control">
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                    <label for="">Hasta</label>
                    <input type="text"name="hastas[]"class="hastas form-control">
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                    <label for="">Color</label>
                    <div id="cp-component-${contador}" class="cp-component input-group">
                        <input type="text" value="#269faf" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
    );

    $('.cp-component').colorpicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used tricky solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="colorpicker_control_template" style="display: none">
    <div class="input-append color colorpicker-component" data-color="rgba(255,146,180,1)" data-color-format="rgba">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" value="rgba(255,146,180,1)" readonly="">
        <span class="color_picker_trick">a</span><span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: rgba(255,146,180,1);"></i></span>
        <i class="btn add_new_picker" type="button" title="Add one more colorpicker">Add new</i>
        <i class="btn remove_picker" type="button" title="Remove this colorpicker">Remove</i>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="colorpicker_wrapper">
    <div class="input-append color colorpicker-component" data-color="rgba(255,146,180,1)" data-color-format="rgba">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" value="rgba(255,146,180,1)" readonly="">
        <span class="color_picker_trick">a</span><span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: rgba(255,146,180,1);"></i></span>
        <i class="btn add_new_picker" type="button" title="Add one more colorpicker">Add new</i>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
span.color_picker_trick {
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 26px;
height: 30px;
cursor: pointer; }
```

Js:

```
        $('div.colorpicker-component').colorpicker();

    var ColorPickedDom = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // add new
        $("body div#colorpicker_wrapper").on('click', 'div.colorpicker-component i.add_new_picker', function() {
            var UploadTemplate = $('div#colorpicker_control_template').html();
            $('div#colorpicker_wrapper').append(UploadTemplate);
        });

        // remove clicked
        $("body div#colorpicker_wrapper").on('click', 'div.colorpicker-component i.remove_picker', function() {
            $(this).parent().closest('div.colorpicker-component').remove();
        });

        // the trick
        $('div#colorpicker_wrapper').on('click', 'div.colorpicker-component span.color_picker_trick', function(e) {
            ColorPickedDom = $(this).parent();
            $(ColorPickedDom).colorpicker('show');
        });

    });
```

Git example: https://github.com/CosmicLaca/multiple_bootstrap_colorpicker